# Migrate my init.el to spacemacs

Tags: init-file, spacemacs

Running emacs 25.2.2. Currently I am trying out spacemacs, primarily because I found the keybindings more intuitive.

I needed some stuff from my `init.el` to move to `.spacemacs` before I can start using it fully.

I have set a lot of variables set using customize command. I could easily copy these over to `.spacemacs`. And they are now working as expected.

But there are some `defun`s and a lot of keyboard macros.

Should I just copy them over to `.spacemacs` and put them at the end of the file or is there a more formal/ structured/ recommended/ better way of doing it?

Comment: You should be fine with just copying over your old configuration to spacemacs if it works. Whether you want to start from scratch is up to you, and configuration which doesn't break things should be just fine. There might be some facilities spacemacs adds to customize things you've customized already, but I don't know if there's a reason to spend time looking for them, especially if the amount of customization you have is substantial.